# Python process ends with exit code -11 when trying to play audio

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, exit-code

I'm trying to write a program for a raspberry pi 3b in python that plays a random loaded .wav file when an on board button is pressed, but it gets to the point of attempting to play the sound then stops the program with exit code -11. What does that exit code mean, and how do I fix it. this program is meant to be run on my person without a screen, as I'm writing it for use in a haunted forest. My plan is to set it to run before I leave for work, then when necessary, press the button and scare one of the people going through the forest.

For the sake of simplicity, here is the function that I wrote and the troublesome code, not the rest of the program (button pin = 3):

```py
def PlaySound(file):
    with open(Path + file, "rb") as WaveFileRB:
        Wave = WaveFileRB
        pygame.mixer.music.load(Wave)
        pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0,start=0.0,fade_ms=0)
    while pygame.mixer.music.get.busy() == True:
         continue


while True:
     time.sleep(0.1)
     if GPIO.input(ButtonPin) == GPIO.LOW:
         time.sleep(0.5)
         File = random.choice(SoundFiles)
         PlaySound(File)
     else:
         continue
```

Essentially, I've tried googling the problem, and nothing has really told me how to fix it. The closest I've gotten was someone on a forum for like 9 years ago asking roughly the same question as I am, and several people saying that an easy fix is to remove SFX all together, which I can't do because its the whole point of the program.

Comment: A negative exit code is a signal.  Signal 11 is SIGSEGV -- segmentation fault.  Are you sure all your file names are visible in the location you expect?  Are you missing a slash in between, perhaps?

Comment: @TimRoberts The files are under /home/username/Music/sfx. i dont really know how to check if they are visible or not. im going to write a simple program to test if it can just play audio. i know the pi is detecting my button presses because i have it print into the console "button pressed" when i press the button.

Comment: @TimRoberts the files are visible, and the RPi plays sound fine, but the main program still doesnt play sound. it seems like trying to trigger the sound from a button is to blame.

Comment: And you have an audio device hooked up to your Pi?

Comment: @TimRoberts i do, and i changed my program around a bit so it doesnt give me that exit code anymore. now its just a matter of getting to read the file

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error when using PyAudio and threading on my Raspberry Pi. Lots of debugging was unsuccessful, until i now finally changed the audio playback from `PyAudio` to `sounddevice` (`pip install sounddevice`) and the error went away.

You could possibly solve it as well by replacing your `pygame` playback with the `sounddevice` package.